# Resource Governor not limiting CPU / RAM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, resource-governor

I have an application that is consuming a lot of resources, actually this application drives CPU to. 99% which makes the server unusable (I think there is nothing I can do about this as is a third-party application).

So I decided to create a Resource Pool specific to this Application.

After creating the Resource Pool I limited this application to 2 cores and 25% CPU / RAM, it worked perfectly, CPU of the server was at 25-26% all the time when before it was at 99%...

Then I decided to remove the MAXDOP for the Resource Group and then the application went to 99% again... I have seen that the application query opened 8 parallel processes so I assumed that puting the resouce pool at MAX 10% would do the job (10*8 = 80% CPU) but if I don't limit the Cores then I'm getting again a 99% CPU consumption...

What am I doing wrong?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to limit the CPU of a resource pool then you need to use the `CAP_CPU_PERCENT` setting:

> This settings is a hard cap limit on the CPU bandwidth for all
>   requests in the resource pool. Workloads associated with the pool can
>   use CPU capacity above the value of MAX_CPU_PERCENT if it is
>   available, but not above the value of CAP_CPU_PERCENT.

The `MAX_CPU_PERCENT` setting is designed to limit the average CPU usage. If there isn't contention on the server then it can be ignored:

> If there is available CPU capacity, the workload uses it up to 100
>   percent. The maximum value only applies when there is contention for
>   CPU resources.

You can read more about different resource pool settings in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor-resource-pool).

Comment: Just note that CAP_CPU_PERCENT does have some significant challenges, as outlined by Robert L. Davis: https://sqlsoldier.net/wp/sqlserver/tsql2sday83resourcegovernorcpu_cap